# EventTrigger in DataTemplate MouseEnter Grid does not work

Tags: wpf

Why the following event triggers of grid MouseEnter/MouseLeave not working. As a workaround, I used `IsMouseOver`.

There are no errors, binding errors, simply it does not work without any idea what is the reason.

Any Idea?
Just to pass validation

Here is the code

```
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate.Resources>
                            <Storyboard x:Key="OnGrdMouseEnter">
                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Item">
                                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#2097B5"/>
                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="TimeFrameItemText">
                                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White"/>
                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                            <Storyboard x:Key="OnGrdMouseLeave">
                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Item">
                                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="TimeFrameItemText">
                                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Black"/>
                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </DataTemplate.Resources>
                            <StackPanel >
                            <!--MouseLeftButtonDown="MenuItem_MouseLeftButtonDown" 
                                MouseLeftButtonUp="UIElement_OnMouseLeftButtonUp"-->
                            <Grid  Cursor="Hand" Name="Item" IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}">
                                
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="1"></RowDefinition>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                                    <!--<RowDefinition Height="1"></RowDefinition>-->
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.InputBindings>
                                    <MouseBinding Command="{Binding ItemCommand}" MouseAction="LeftClick"/>
                                </Grid.InputBindings>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="TimeFrameItemText" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"
                                                   Foreground="{StaticResource PopupForegroundBrush}"  Height="22" Text="{Binding TimeFrameLabel}"
                                                  Width="{Binding ElementName=popup, Path=DataContext.OptionTextWidth,Converter={StaticResource DummyConverter}}">

                                <TextBlock>
                               
                            </Grid>
                            <Rectangle Width="Auto" Height="1" Visibility="{Binding IsLast,Converter={StaticResource BoolVisibilityConverter},ConverterParameter=Inverse}" Fill="{StaticResource PopupSeparatorBrush}"/>
                        </StackPanel>

                        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                            <!--<Trigger SourceName="Item" Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="Item" Property="Background" Value="#2097B5"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="TimeFrameItemText" Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                            </Trigger>-->
                            
                           <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.MouseEnter" SourceName="Item">
                                <BeginStoryboard x:Name="OnGrdMouseEnter_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource OnGrdMouseEnter}"/>
                            </EventTrigger>
                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.MouseLeave" SourceName="Item">
                                <BeginStoryboard x:Name="OnGrdMouseLeave_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource OnGrdMouseLeave}"/>
                            </EventTrigger>
                        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
           
         </Border>
    </Popup>
```

Comment: Try to set Grid's Background color to Transparent

Comment: Yes the triggers are working once i set the Grid background transparent.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` event working for grid, set the background color of the grid to `Transparent`.